# Many-to-many start schema JPA

Tags: java, database, spring, jpa

I found [here](http://javasampleapproach.com/spring-framework/spring-data/spring-jpa-many-to-many) a good article about designing the many-to-many schema with JPA.

```
 @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "student_subject", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Subject> subjects;
```

My question is, can I map a start schema, for example on JoinColumn I want to add multiple tables. It is possible?